# bootstrap buttons formatting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I'm trying to create eye-friendly 4x4 keyboard, using ONLY bootstrap. Unfortunately, although I divided buttons into groups, they don't seem to be formatted - separate lines have got various lengths; moreover, some of the buttons have got rounded edges. In shortcut, it looks as below:

[image]

Is there any possibility **NOT to use CSS** to fix it? I mean, my target is to format it into one big square, divided into 16 smaller.
Here's my code:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button id = "1" value="1" class="btn btn-info">1</button>
<button id = "2" value="2" class="btn btn-info">2</button>
<button id = "3" value="3" class="btn btn-info">3</button> 
<button id = "plus2" value="plus2" class="btn btn-primary">+</button>
</div><br> <div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button id = "4" value="4" class="btn btn-info">4</button>
<button id = "5" value="5" class="btn btn-info">5</button>
<button id = "6" value="6" class="btn btn-info">6</button> 
<button id="minus2" value="minus2" class="btn btn-primary">-</button>
</div><br> <div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button id = "7" value="7" class="btn btn-info">7</button>
<button id = "8" value="8" class="btn btn-info">8</button>
<button id = "9" value="9" class="btn btn-info">9</button> 
<button id = "razy2" value="razy2" class="btn btn-primary">*</button> 
</div><br><div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button id = "0" value="0" class="btn btn-info">0</button>
<button id = "p" value="p" class="btn btn-primary">,</button>
<button id = "rowna" value="rowna"  class="btn btn-success">=</button>
<button id = "dziel2" value="dziel2" class="btn btn-primary">/</button>
</div>
```

When I replace these small groups into one big group, first and last buttons have got rounded corners and lines still have various lengths.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Stuff like only the first and last button in a group having rounded corners is the default bootstrap applies. If you want all of the to be rounded, then don’t put them into a `btn-group`. Apart from that, you will most likely have to write a bit of CSS your own to achieve the look you want.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't any built-in amazing bootstrap thing to format it automatically. I'll create some CSS then. Thank you, guys :)

Comment: thnks @lawstud for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the button size, it depends on the content inside that button; like if you write 'Add' then button's width will automatically increase. For this ',' you have to fix width of the button and all buttons will display with the same width.

Answer (score 0):

You need it tabulating.

No additional CSS should be required, and you do it like so:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="btn-group">
    <td><button id = "1" value="1" class="btn btn-info">1</button></td>
    <td><button id = "2" value="2" class="btn btn-info">2</button></td>
    <td><button id = "3" value="3" class="btn btn-info">3</button></td>
    <td><button id = "plus2" value="plus2" class="btn btn-primary">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="btn-group">
    <td><button id = "4" value="4" class="btn btn-info">4</button></td>
    <td><button id = "5" value="5" class="btn btn-info">5</button></td>
    <td><button id = "6" value="6" class="btn btn-info">6</button> </td>
    <td><button id="minus2" value="minus2" class="btn btn-primary">-</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="btn-group">
    <td><button id = "7" value="7" class="btn btn-info">7</button></td>
    <td><button id = "8" value="8" class="btn btn-info">8</button></td>
    <td><button id = "9" value="9" class="btn btn-info">9</button> </td>
    <td><button id = "razy2" value="razy2" class="btn btn-primary">*</button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="btn-group">
    <td><button id = "0" value="0" class="btn btn-info">0</button></td>
    <td><button id = "p" value="p" class="btn btn-primary">,</button></td>
    <td><button id = "rowna" value="rowna"  class="btn btn-success">=</button></td>
    <td><button id = "dziel2" value="dziel2" class="btn btn-primary">/</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Just as long as all the btn-group class isn't doing too much, the above will work.

If it's still broken then paste the btn-group css and I'll fix it.

Comment: There's one problem with your solurion - when I paste it without `class="btn-group"`, it doesn't format the buttons. When I added it everywhere, whole table merged into one line...

Comment: Paste the btn, btn-group, btn-info and btn-primary css declarations and I will fix it

Comment: I cannot paste css declarations of those things - these are built-in bootstrap features. I didn't create any css file so far.

Comment: Okey dokey. I'm just on my way into a meeting now, but I can fix it when I get back. Apologies in advance if it over-runs, but I'll definitely get a fix for you by tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just gave up, deleted btn-groups and used css to set width. It's not exactly what I wanted to write but it looks fine anyway.

Answer (score -1):

## For the button size, it depends on the content inside that button; like if you write 'Add' then button's width will automatically increase. For this ',' you have to fix width of the button and all buttons will display with the same width.

Define CSS:

button.btn{width: 33px;}

Comment: what happened to your answer?

Comment: Define CSS:

button.btn{width: 33px;} 

#lawstud this is my answer. i m already update

Comment: I tried really hard to avoid using css but it seems that your answer PLUS deleting btn-groups gives me what I wanted. Thanks.